# ReactJS Table - creating hook to add padding to Table header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jsx

I'm working with a global Table definition for which I want to add left padding to the header, specifically something like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div({
    paddingLeft:32,
}

<Table>
    <Table.Header>`
        <Table.HeaderCell><Wrapper>Title</Wrapper></Table.HeaderCell>
    </Table.Header>
</Table>
```

However, I don't want to simply edit the Table definition, I want to create a hook (say `useTableWithPaddedHeader()`) so that in the future, anywhere I want to implement a Table with a padded header I can call the hook. How do I go about creating such a hook?

I'm not really sure where to begin. I'm not familiar with creating hooks in JS and don't know how to replicate every part of the Table except for how the Header is padded.

Comment: Why not just give the table a class name and use CSS to style all the table header?

Comment: Do you already have a base `useTable()`? If not, let us know.

Comment: This isn't really how hooks are used. Hooks provide data, not components. Your `Table` component could have a property like `paddedHeader: boolean` and conditionally render the markup based on the value of the prop.

Comment: @adsy yes I do have a base useTable() already

Comment: @EricHaynes what if I'm unable to modify the Table component?